# React highlight when clicked

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How to highlight the  after the user clicked?

```
   <Box py={2}>
      <Grid container width="330px">
        <Grid container direction="column" item xs align="left">
          <Grid item>
            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              className="locationTitle"
              display="block"
            >
              {' '}
              {location.name}{' '}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Typography variant="body" display="block">
        {' '}
        {location.address.street1}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
```

css

```
.css-1yjo05o:hover{
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

the hover is fine but when i tried to `:focus` and `:target`, it doesnt work

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `How to highlight the after the user clicked?`? User clicked on what?!

Comment: what i mean is when the user click on the <li> it will highlight or change background

Comment: `:focus` and `:target` is not available for each type of html elements, you might have to use different class e.g `active` or something to change background when element is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never style the hashes generated by the Mui styling engine. They are not static. Instead, you want an `onClick` listener that toggles a `className` (if you are using CSS) or an SX prop (if you are using @mui/material).

```js
const [highlight, setHighlight] = useState(false)

<Box 
  py={2} 
  onClick={() => setHighlight(!highlight)} 
  sx={{ bgcolor: highlight ? 'lightgrey' : 'unset' }}
>
```

Of course this has the potential to highlight more than 1 box at a time. If you want 1 box at a time, you have to lift the state up to the parent component and use the child's index to toggle the highlight. [Demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/list-highlight-demo-htz43)

Comment: I can already see the highlighting but what if when I click a second time on another list, the previous or first click will be lost>?

Comment: `Of course this has the potential to highlight more than 1 box at a time. If you want 1 box at a time, you have to lift the state up to the parent component and use the child's index to toggle the highlight.` can you provide an example on this?

Comment: @kaito Sure, I added it into the answer

Comment: hello, it works now but i am having trouble aligning your answer to my code :(

Comment: can we move in chat? so that i can give you my code?

Comment: ive added a file name "mine" here https://codesandbox.io/s/list-highlight-demo-forked-gcfsp?file=/src/mine.js please check

Comment: @kaito Sorry, I can't help you right now. Busy with new year stuff. I'll be back later if you haven't figured it out already. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70540618/react-on-and-off-highlight please see this