# React on and off highlight

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a list of data that displays in a `Collapse`, I just want that to highlight for every click of user in a list but ***one at a time when highlighting***

to understand better, please see this sample

https://codesandbox.io/s/list-highlight-demo-forked-ww0op

```
const [highlight, setHighlight] = useState(false)
const handleClick = () => {
   if (on) set(null)
   else set(index)
}
  <Collapse in={viewLocationList} sx={{ my: '2px' }}>
    {!!searchParameter && (
      <Box className="rounded-scrollbar widget-result-container"
      onClick={handleClick}
      sx={{
        my: 1,
        bgcolor: on && "lightgrey",
        "&:hover": { bgcolor: on && "lightgrey" }
      }}
      >
        {filteredLocations.map((location, key, on) => (
          <LocationWidgetItem
            key={key}
            location={location}
            onClickLocation={setActiveLocation}
            index={key} on={highlight === key} set={setHighlight}
          />
        ))}
      </Box>
    )}
  </Collapse>
```

this is the error of current code

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting to happen with your output?

Comment: I want to highlight result 1 at a time,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, it seems to be working. Can you explain more?

Comment: I want to apply the functionality in the sample to my code, the only problem is I don't know how to align the code in the example with my current code

Comment: Your handleClick method is in the wrong place. Put it inside LocationWidgetItem

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, You are not passing the "on" prop from the parent component to your item component as done in example.

[image]

Comment: hello bro, i just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Your sandbox is correct. The difference is that you are trying to pass an `on` prop from your `filteredLocations` map that does not exist. It is even not needed, since you are declaring the `on` with `highlight === key` comparison later on.

Instead of

```
{filteredLocations.map((location, key, on) => (...)}
```

try to render your list with:

```
{filteredLocations.map((location, key) => (...)}
```